# Qt Mouse Control of Rotaries on touch and non-touch devices

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, touch

I have implemented rotary widget in Qt. When the user clicks the rotary, the mouse cursor is hidden, and dragging the mouse left/down turns the rotary anti-clockwise, and dragging the mouse right/up turns the rotary clockwise. When the mouse is released, the mouse cursor is set to the original position of the click. Implemented like this:

```
void RotaryWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *MouseEvent)
{
    mMousePos = QCursor::pos();
    mPreviousPos = MouseEvent->pos();
    setCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
}

void RotaryWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *MouseEvent)
{
    QCursor::setPos(mMousePos);
    unsetCursor();
}

void RotaryWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *MouseEvent)
{
    QPoint DeltaPos = MouseEvent->pos() - mPreviousPos;
    // Use DeltaPos to move my rotary
    mPreviousPos = MouseEvent->pos();
}
```

The benefit of this is that when there are several rotaries in a row, it is quicker for a user to make adjustments.

There is a bug with the above code, in that if the cursor gets to the edge of the screen, the mouse cannot be moved so the rotary does not move. However, the user cannot see the cursor, so it is a problem. I changed `mouseMoveEvent` to fix it:

```
void RotaryWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *MouseEvent)
{
    if(MouseEvent->globalPos() == mMousePos)
    {
        mPreviousPos = mapFromGlobal(mMousePos);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        QCursor::setPos(mMousePos);
    }
    QPoint DeltaPos = MouseEvent->pos() - mPreviousPos;
    // Use DeltaPos to move my rotary
    mPreviousPos = MouseEvent->pos();
}
```

Essentially, every time the mouse is moved, the change is calculated, and then the cursor is set back to the original press position (so it can never go off the screen). The `if` at the top makes sure we don't continuously set the mouse position to the original position over and over.

This works fine on non touch-screen devices, but on touch screen devices, `QCursor::setPos()` does not work because I cannot programmatically set the position of a finger on a screen!

I have failed to think of a solution that satisfies all of the requirements I have described. If there was a way to detect whether the user is using a touch screen it could be fixed, but I can find no such function in Qt.

Comment: how should it behaves when a user move and keep touching at the edge of the screen? Does the rotary keeps moving??

Comment: @UmNyobe On a touch screen device, if they get to the edge of the screen, the rotary won't move anymore. On a non-touch screen device, the idea is that they can never get to the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to force mouse to the click position, you can check if mouse is on the edge or beyond the edge, and if it is, use constant increment for delta (last move):

```
void RotaryWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *MouseEvent)
{
    QPoint DeltaPos;
    if(!isInsideWindow(MouseEvent))
    {
       DeltaPos = mPrevDeltaPos;
    }
    else
    {
       DeltaPos = MouseEvent->pos() - mPreviousPos;
       mPrevDeltaPos = DeltaPos;
       // Use DeltaPos to move my rotary
       mPreviousPos = MouseEvent->pos();
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to calculate DeltaPos base on global mouse coordinates rather then local coordinates relative to the window 0 - since only difference between two mouse coordinates is of interest, position does not need to be linked to the window. In that case, widget would work both for touch and mouse operated screen as intended - regardless of how cursor is positioned with respect to the window frame, same movements of a mouse/finger would change orientation in a same way.

Comment: This doesn't meet my requirements. The Rotary should appear to work in the same way to the user regardless of the actual mouse position. As the cursor is hidden, the user wouldn't know they are at the edge, and therefore the Rotary would start working in a different way without any feedback given to the user with your solution.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with your point about feedback. Please see edit.